# Fast AppleWatch Data Sending

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch, data-transfer, watchconnectivity

Does anyone know of a faster way of getting data from the Apple Watch that is faster than the Watch Connectivity framework? I'm trying to access the gyroscope and accelerometer data in real time (or as close to real time as I can get) and the Watch Connectivity seems to be operating very slowly. The console in Xcode is able to receive data very fast from the watch. Is Apple using another type of communication that hasn't been opened up to developers?

I'm working in an academic proof-of-concept environment so it doesn't have to be elegant. I've tried some libraries like ilibmobiledevice and node-ios-device that pipe device syslogs into Terminal, but neither seem to be able to support AppleWatch. I've also looked at some UDP options but that looks to be shut down on the AppleWatch as well...

Comment: If it connects to the phone via Bluetooth, you might be SOL. Bluetooth isn't known for its speed. Does the Watch have WiFi? You could host a server on the app and have the watch send data to it.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think it uses a combo of Bluetooth and WiFi. I know some network transfer options are limited on the watch for security reasons, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've found that the only viable solution "should" be the MultipeerConnectivity framework used on macOS, iOS, and tvOS to communicate over WiFi.
Unfortunately, it seems that the reason Apple don't implement this for watchOS is because it is too demanding on the Watch battery, hence why WatchConnectivity and low-level Bluetooth is the only option. Apple have weighed power consumption against transfer rate and clearly decided that MultipeerConnectivity isn't possible.